# PHPTAL i18n Call to a member function on a non-object Error

Tags: php, internationalization, phptal

I'm using PHPTAL in my project I'm able to successfully implement it almost all the cases except when I want to use its i18n services. I constantly get errors "Call to a member function on a non-object"

I've tried searching the net forums etc. but not found any solution, will really appreciate if somebody can help me out.

Answer (score 4):

Its heartily disappointing that no one answered my question so here I'm finally with the solution and answering my own question.

By default there is no translator set by PHPTAL in order to translate your text from one language to another. So you've to do it on your own. There are some steps give below to do this . . .

**Step 1.** Create a new php file( e.g. *MyTranslator.php* ) and generate a new class for example *PHPTAL_MyTranslator* and store it inside the PHPTAL folder. This class will implement the interface *PHPTAL_TranslationService*. There are five functions in this interface but the function of our concern is only *translate*. So just add a declaration for rest of the functions and write code for the translate function. The class I've written and used in my case is :

`class PHPTAL_MyTranslator implements PHPTAL_TranslationService {

    /**
     * current execution context
     */
    protected $_context = null;

    /**
     * @param string (name of the language)
     * @return string (language you've just set)
     *
     * This method sets translation language.
     * Name of the language is a dir name where you keep your translation files
     */
    public function setLanguage() {
    }

    public function __construct( $context ) {
        $this->_context = $context;
    }

    /**
     * @param string (translation file name)
     * @return void
     *
     * You can separate translations in several files, and use only when needed.
     * Use this method to specify witch translation file you want to
     * use for current controller.
     */
    public function useDomain( $domain ) {
    }

    /**
     * Set an interpolation var.
     * Replace all ${key}s with values in translated strings.
     */
    public function setVar( $key, $value ) {
    }

    /**
     * Translate a text and interpolate variables.
     */
    public function translate( $key, $htmlescape=true ) {
        $value = $key;
        if( empty( $value ) ) {
            return $key;
        }
        while( preg_match( '/\${(.*?)\}/sm', $value, $m ) ) {
            list( $src, $var ) = $m;
            if( !array_key_exists( $var, $this->_context ) ) {
                $err = sprintf( 'Interpolation error, var "%s" not set', $var );
                throw new Exception( $err );
            }
            $value = str_replace( $src, $this->_context->$var, $value );
        }
        return gettext( $value );
    }

    /**
     * Not implemented yet, default encoding is used
     */
    public function setEncoding( $encoding ) {
    }
}`

**Step 2.** Now open the *PHPTAL.php* file and modify the constructor of *PHPTAL* class. Add a line to this function as shown below . . . . .

Before

`public function __construct($path=false)
{
    $this->_path = $path;
    $this->_globalContext = new StdClass();
    $this->_context = new PHPTAL_Context();
    $this->_context->setGlobal($this->_globalContext);

    if (function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir')) {
    ............`

After

`public function __construct($path=false)
{
    $this->_path = $path;
    $this->_globalContext = new StdClass();
    $this->_context = new PHPTAL_Context();
    $this->_context->setGlobal($this->_globalContext);
    //Set translator here
    $this->setTranslator( new PHPTAL_MyTranslator( $this->_context ) );

    if (function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir')) {
    .............`

These two simple steps will make your *i18n:attributes* as well as *i18n:translate* attributes to work properly.

Cheers...

Comment: You don't need to modify PHPTAL's constructor — you can set translator anytime before `execute()`.

Comment: Setting translator inside PHPTAL's constructor will reduce the overhead of setting it in every php file before execute().